# Area Under Exterior Wooden Deck

Tags: concrete, exterior, patio

I have an external wooden deck, and the area underneath it always has moisture which makes it an unusable area.

I'm assuming the moisture is because it is shaded almost all the time from the house and trees.

The area underneath the deck is mostly dirt with some old gravel.

Not thinking the price (yet), what are my options?

Can I place concrete, or stones? Or because of the moisture it could be a problem?

Or, is it best to add gravel to see if the moisture goes away?

Any other ideas?

Comment: A picture would help a lot.  Stand back away from the house so we can see incline and drainage patterns.

Comment: what about the moisture makes it unusable? it is smelly, humid, etc? are you concerned about rot? do you want to block symptoms or treat the issue? for some cases, a tarp over the ground and under the deck would suffice...

Comment: @dandavis it's wet so if you step on it you get muddy. other houses next to us had the same issue and have a little patio. I would like to treat the issue.

Comment: Found this link which has good information: http://www.fairfaxcounty.gov/nvswcd/drainageproblem/wet-yard.htm 
I think its grading problem and Poor infiltration. I'll update when I have some more info.